# Error deploying Shiny app: Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 20268

Tags: r, shiny

EDIT: it seems the issue may be coming from the ggridges package, does this work with Shiny?

I have built a R Shiny app that works fine locally but falls down when I try to deploy it

I think the issue is with the drop down menus, but I'm not sure. I have one data frame that provides the data for both plots, with the reactive event generating a temporary data frame each time a selection is made (including when no selection is made and all data is used). I've scoured the web and Stack Overflow thoroughly, but haven't managed to solve it.

When I try to deploy the app the browser opens and the drop down menus appear but the plots do not. Checking the logs in Shiny showed the error message contained in the post title.

Any help is appreciated and I can provide more info if needed.

Below is my code.

Thanks!

ui:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("test"),

  inputPanel(
    selectInput("region", 
                "Choose a region:", 
                choices = c("All Regions", "Midwest", "Northeast", "South", "West"),
                selected = "All Regions"),
    selectInput("year", 
                "Choose a year:", 
                choices = c("All Years", sapply(1999:2016, as.character)),
                selected = "All Years")
  ),
  plotOutput("plot")
)
)
```

server:

```
library(shiny)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggridges)
library(cowplot)
library(magrittr)
theme_set(theme_grey())

drug_eco <- read_csv("drug_eco.csv")

usa_region <- read_csv("usa_region.csv")

drug_eco[,1:2] <- drug_eco[,1:2] %>% lapply(factor)
drug_eco <- drug_eco %>% 
  mutate(drug_deaths_per_100k = round(drug_deaths/(population/100000), 1))

colnames(usa_region) <- colnames(usa_region) %>% tolower()
usa_region[,1:4] <- usa_region[,1:4] %>% lapply(factor)

drug_eco <- drug_eco %>%  
  left_join(usa_region[,c(1,3)], by = "state")

drug_eco_long <- drug_eco %>% 
  select(c(1:2,5:7)) %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -c(1:2,5))

drug_eco_long$variable <- drug_eco_long$variable %>% 
  factor(levels = c("drug_deaths_per_100k", "unemployment_rate"),
         labels = c("Drug Related Deaths per 100k Population", "Unemployment Rate %"))

fix_x <- data.frame(
  value = c(0, 55, 0, 15),
  year = c(1, 18, 1, 18),
  variable = c(rep("Drug Related Deaths per 100k Population", 2),
               rep("Unemployment Rate %", 2))
)

gfc_annotation <- data.frame(
  value = 45, 
  year = "2010", 
  variable = "Drug Related Deaths per 100k Population",
  label = "GFC"
) 

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  density_df <- reactive({
    if (input$region == "All Regions") {
      temp_1 <- drug_eco_long
    } else {
      temp_1 <- filter(drug_eco_long, region == input$region)
    }
  })

  point_df <- reactive({
    if (input$region == "All Regions" & input$year == "All Years") {
      temp_2 <- drug_eco_long
    } else if (input$region != "All Regions" & input$year == "All Years") {
      temp_2 <- filter(drug_eco_long, region == input$region)
    } else if (input$region == "All Regions" & input$year != "All Years") {
      temp_2 <- filter(drug_eco_long, year == input$year) 
    } else {
      temp_2 <- filter(drug_eco_long, region == input$region & year == input$year)
    }
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    p1 <- ggplot(density_df(), aes(value, year, fill = variable)) + 
      geom_density_ridges(jittered_points = T, 
                          position = position_points_jitter(width = 0.05, height = 0),
                          point_shape = "|",
                          point_size = 2.5,
                          size = 0.5, 
                          scale = 1.5, 
                          alpha = 0.8, 
                          rel_min_height = 0.005) +
      scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
      facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free_x") +
      geom_blank(data = fix_x) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, NA)) +
      annotate("rect", ymin = 10, ymax = 14, xmin = 0, xmax = Inf, alpha = 0.1) +
      geom_text(data = gfc_annotation, aes(label = label), size = 5) +
      labs(title = "test",
           subtitle = "",
           x = "", 
           y = "Year") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
            legend.position = "none") 

    p2 <- ggplot(point_df(), 
                 aes(fct_reorder2(state, -variable, -value), value, colour = variable)) +
      geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.8) +
      scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 50)) +
      coord_flip() +
      labs(title = "test", 
           subtitle = "test", 
           x = "State (inc. DC)", 
           y = "", 
           colour = "Variable") +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
            legend.position = "bottom") +
      guides(colour = guide_legend(title.position = "top", title.hjust = 0.5))

    plot_grid(p1, p2)
  })
})
```

Comment: The CSV-files are probably stored locally on your computer and the deployed shiny app has no access to them.

Comment: @hplieninger no, that's not it unfortunately. they're correctly stored in the same directory as the rest of the shiny app R files

Comment: you really should boil your app down to the main parts and you will find the cause of the error. Use breakpoints and print  statements in your render functions to find the root cause. We don't have your csv files to check. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I just face this problem using Rstudio. I decided to update the packages and then upload the app. It worked!!!